# Need help to convert all "mp4" files to "gif" in a folder/directry with ffmpeg and .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, gif, mp4

I need some help.I try work automation to eliminate unnecessary time, I was looking for a way to convert video files to gif files.
So I learned how to make it using ".bat" through Googling, and want to make it a ".bat file" that automatically converts all mp4 files at one click because only one file is converted at a time.

it worked perfect for me. but I got a lot of vidoe files what i have to convert. I installed ffmpeg in my PC(@window)

this is what i find

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
cls

setlocal
echo 프레임 수치를 설정하세요
set /p fps= 

ffmpeg.exe  -i "%~1" -vf "fps=%fps%,scale=860:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" "%~n1.png"
ffmpeg.exe  -i "%~1" -i "%~n1.png" -lavfi "fps=%fps%,scale=860:-1:flags=lanczos [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" "%~n1.gif"

del "%~n1.png"

goto :a
```

Thank for reading it.

Comment: `for %a in (*.mp4) do call YourExistingScript.bat "%a"` (for use directly on the command line; for use in a batch script, use `%%a` instead of `%a?)